Laravel sail and devcontainer - volume option not mounting files
I have been trying to use devcontainer with laravel sail. Im using docker desktop for windows and WSL2. Im using this method of installing vendor assets.
I have added this example to a script and run as initializeCommand option in devcontainer.json.
"initializeCommand": "bash setup.sh"
This outputs the existing directory to make sure the cloned files exist. Then runs the composer install command within a temporary container.
Terminal output: Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
So I assumed that the volume was not mounted correctly, I investigated futher by creating a more permanant container (commented out code below) and listing the output of the volume file plus hardcoding the absolute path to the local project directory (same as pwd).
The volume file 'test' is created, but the contents are empty. It appears the volume is not functioning as expected, what can i do?
setup.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
echo "Contents of the current directory:"
ls -la #shows all project files (need composer.json)

docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

# docker run -d --name temp-container \
#     -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
#     -v "/workspaces/project-name:/test" \
#     laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
#     tail -f /dev/null

# docker exec temp-container sh -c "
#     cd /test &&
#     echo 'Current directory inside the container:' &&
#     pwd && echo 'Contents of the mounted directory:' && 
#     ls -la #no project files (empty directory)
#  "


Are you trying to run this script from within a container?  A docker run -v bind-mount option always mounts a directory from where the Docker daemon is running, probably your WSL environment, and that will be different from the container filesystem if you're invoking docker from inside a container.

I think it is within a container. Im not sure how devcontainer handles creating the dev environment. The script is run at the initilize event, so proabably a temp container that clones the project files before the docker-compose file is read. In the past I have used the workspaces folders to mount docker-compose service data, so I assumed these can be mounted a similar way, if not how can I manage running this script?

If you're using a dev container anyways, can you directly install tools you need (like the PHP interpreter and Composer) directly in the dev container setup, instead of trying to farm out to additional containers?

@DavidMaze Cheers for advise, talking this through I realise how similar the current devcontainer container acts to this created one. I have since installed php and composer directly and it appears to be running smooth now.

Thanks to @DavidMaze for the assist, I resolved the issue by installing php and composer directly instead of in another container. Here is my final outcome, I can now clone to container without issues.
setup.sh
#!/bin/sh

# Ensure Composer dependencies are installed
if [ ! -d "vendor" ]; then

    # Ensure the 'sail' user and group exists
    if ! getent group sail > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        groupadd -g 1000 sail
    fi

    if ! id -u sail > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        useradd -u 1000 -g sail -m sail
    fi

    # Install PHP and Composer
    echo "Installing PHP & Composer..."
    sudo apk update
    sudo apk add php php-cli php-mbstring php-xml php-zip php-openssl php-phar
    curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
  
    echo "Installing Composer dependencies..."
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
else
    echo "Composer dependencies are already installed."
fi


